# mvc XSD namespace is not showing in Configure Namespaces menu in a Maven Web project in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm new to `Java EE` and `Spring` framework, so I'm following an O'Reily tutorial for `Spring MVC` and I have created this `Maven` project under `Spring Tool Suite` and in this I have created a `Spring Bean Configuration File` named `applicationContext.xml` , so when I'm inside this file there's a tab below called Namespaces that shows you multiple `XSD` namespaces where you can choose from, my problem is that `mvc` namespace isn't showing in that list despite following the tutorial step by step.

here is my project structure so far
[image]
what did I miss ?

Answer (score 0):

You must include the spring-mvc dependency in your pom.xml